# Compiler Error in MVC Music Store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have come to the end of the MVC Music Store Tutorial and I have been changing things to my liking, in the tutorial the Store lets you browse by Genre and bring up all Albums in that Genre, I have changed everything so that it brings up a list of all Artists instead and it runs fine until you click on an Artist, it will not bring up the Albums by that Artist.

Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'MVCMusicStore.Models.Album' because 'MVCMusicStore.Models.Album' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

This is the Error Message I am getting, does anyone know how to fix this so it will bring up the albums by the Artist?

```
@model MVCMusicStore.Models.Album

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse Albums";
}

<div class="genre">
    <h3><em>@Model.Artist</em> Albums</h3>

    <ul id="album-list">
        @foreach (var album in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", 
                    new { id = album.AlbumId })">
                    <img alt="@album.Title" 
                        src="@album.AlbumArtUrl" />
                    <span>@album.Title</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: post the code piece where error is shown to get quick solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your ActionResult to return as list of Albums as your model

```
    public ActionResult BrowseAlbums()
    {
        var albums = storeDB.Albums.ToList();

        return View(albums);
    }
```

And then within your view you can iterate through the IEnumerable collection

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>

    ...

    @foreach (var album in Model)
```

Answer (score 3):

Verify the StoreManagerIndexview Page directive.

it should be like below

```
<@Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>>">
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `Album` does not implement `IEnumerable`, which would make sense as it isn't a collection type. I assume that you want to iterate through a collection of `Album` rather than an instance of `Album` itself.

Comment: Yeah thats right, I want to collect the album names from SampleData.cs and I want them to appear when you click on an artist name, this should hopefully bring up all albums by that artist